# How to plausibly reanimate a person?

Tags: science-based, death, life

What hypothetical scientific procedure could be used to reanimate someone who is brain dead. I am aware that it is possible to bring someone back if they are clinically dead which is where a vital organ stops. But what procedure would be used to bring a biologically dead person back to life? How expensive would it be? Would it involve electricity like Frankenstein or artificial enzymes?

Comment: The key is having a good Igor.

Comment: What Frankenstein used to induce life is never explained in the original novel - it's actually skipped over. The electricity is a function of the first film adaptation, as that was when technology was starting to take off and there was a fear of out-of-control electronics, which the film capitalized on.

Answer (score 1):

**Robot brain.**

When I read "[brain dead](https://www.kidney.org/atoz/content/braindeath)" I think about a person who is disconnected from life support because the brain is dead.   The rest of the body may be OK and in fact such people are used as sources for organ donation.  Bringing a dead brain back to life depends on why the brain is dead.  I think it is fair to say that you should not call it dead if you can possibly bring it back to life.

As regards the body of a brain dead person, organs in good shape will do ok if you give them oxygen, water and nutrients.  Mechanical ventilators (robots!) can take over the oxygenation function usually driven by the brain, and keep the body warm and living.  If you had a robot that could more thoroughly take over the other functions of the brain, the body could get up and do things.  The trick would be integrating the robot brain into the thousands of fussy little nerves that transmit brain direction out to the body and receive sensory inputs back.  That is still science fiction but plausible for fiction.

The robot brain would not be a human.  It could serve as a remote, so the reanimated body could be a drone.  Or the robot brain could have an artificial intelligence and autonomy.  Or both.

For a fiction you can make this as fancy or unfancy as you want.  You could plug the robot in and let it establish neural connections over a few months while the body was sustained.  That would be good for a fiction as the robot brain would come on line little by little - first basic life support, then gross motor, and bit by bit the rest would come up.  Maybe people do this routinely in your world, or maybe it is a wild experiment.

Answer (score 0):

The is an ambiguous question because certain aspects of death are not well understood.

Being dead vs. alive has a clear scientific definition and is determined by brain death. Being brain dead is defined as having a brain sustain such damage such that it will never be able to provide fundamental life support functions (breathing, heart beat...etc) again.

Now the tricky part. In some instances brain death is obvious...massive trauma for instance, other times it is less obvious. Since we don't have a simple way of being able tell how an apparently healthy brain will function in an other-wise obviously dying person there are some tests which have been developed to try to determined brain death. The apnea test is the most well known, but issues can arise when testing patients whose lungs are not properly functioning. Usually this is not a problem but there are instances in which addition tests must correlate the apnea test for brain death to be pronounced.

So the question is, how is a brain dead persons brain fundamentally different than an alive persons brain? The answer to that is still the subject of scientific debate. There is no consensus theory for the cause of brain death...that is to say what is the determining factors for when an alive brain switches to a dead brain. The brain (which presumably stores the "person", this too is not well understood from a scientific standpoint) decays very rapidly when dead, so even if we could "switch" the brain back on upon brain death, we would have to do so very quickly after death as the brain would quickly become structurally damaged beyond repair.